# Cannot add teradata.client.provider.dll reference in vs2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reference, teradata, multitargeting

I Try to add Teradata.client.provider.dll in a project in vs2017 .net2. and compile, I recieve an error: 
The primary reference "Teradata.Client.Provider, Version=14.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=76b417ee2e04956c, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Teradata.Client.Provider, Version=14.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=76b417ee2e04956c, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

Strangely in vs2005 .net2 There is no such problem .

dll version is 14.11.0.0
Its runtime version is v2.0.50727

Comment: Do you have .NET 3.5/4.0 installed in the system?

Comment: Yes obviously I do